# Why does R hang when using NGramTokenizer?

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I try to construct a Document-Term Meatrix from a corpus. The commands I used are:

```
library(parallel)
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
library(topicmodels)
library(RTextTools)
cl=makeCluster(detectCores())
invisible(clusterEvalQ(cl, library(tm)))
invisible(clusterEvalQ(cl, library(RWeka))) 
invisible(clusterEvalQ(cl, library(topicmodels)))
invisible(clusterEvalQ(cl, library(RTextTools)))
myCorpus <-Corpus(DirSource("/home/neeph/Test/DMOZ_Business"), encoding="UTF-8", readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)
removeAmp <- function(x) gsub("&amp;", "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeAmp)
removeWWW <- function(x) gsub("www[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWWW)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("SMART"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stripWhitespace)
summary(myCorpus)
```

A corpus with 696 text documents

The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
Available tags are:
  create_date creator 
Available variables in the data frame are:
  MetaID

```
myDtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1,Inf)))
```

Everything works fine upto this stage, if I do not include tokenizing. However, when I run the code with the following alteration:

```
dictCorpus <- myCorpus
myDtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordlengths=c(1,Inf),tokenize=NGramTokenizer, dictionary=dictCorpus))
```

it hangs. I have kept it running overnight, but no results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:

```
summary(myDtm)      
Error in order(list(i = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
   unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 4):

`Neep Hazarika`'s solution didn't fix the hang problem for me.  I worked around it by specifying the default number of threads:

```
# Sets the default number of threads to use
options(mc.cores=1)
```

Since the `NGramTokenizer` seems to hang on the `parallel::mclapply` call, changing the number of threads seems to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Just have to initialize the JVM before calling RWeka routines. So start with:

library(rJava)
.jinit(parameters="-Xmx128g")

before loading RWeka library.